# AWS Route 53 domain name still not pointing to IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, domain-name

I registered a domain name on AWS Route 53, then deleted the generated hosted zone that they automatically generated for the domain and replaced it with this one: [image]

The values in the NS record match the name servers of the registered domain

[image]

I haven't modified these settings for almost 72 hours, and the registered domain name still doesn't point to the IP I specified. Any idea why? It all looks correct to me.

Comment: nslookup zcomb.buzz    
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
Server:         8.8.4.4
Address:        8.8.4.4#53

** server can't find zcomb.buzz: SERVFAIL 
I tried to check your domain but it does not work. Why do you need to delete the old one?

Comment: @AshBlake in retrospect I should have just modified the auto-generated one, but i created a new one. But if the records end up being the same I would guess it shouldn't make a difference

Comment: I think the differences is in the NS records, it must be the same as the previous one because it is where your records in. You should connect to AWS support now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of frustration and waiting I solved this by:

1. Deleting the hosted zone associated with the domain.
2. Creating a new hosted zone for the domain. Route 53 auto-generates an NS record with 4 pre-filled name server addresses
3. Going to Domains > Registered Domains > (domain) > Add or edit name servers. Deleting the four name servers there and replacing them with the four that Route 53 gave me in step 2 (without the periods at the end).

Within a few min the domain started pointing to the IP I specified and was picked up by a bunch of DNS servers as measured by https://dnschecker.org/

Hope this helps someone, someday